# How can I see EBS growth trends?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-ebs

I have an EC2 instance with an EBS of 400 GB. I have been asked if there is a way to see how much space is being used per day or per month of that EBS.

I am new to AWS and I am not sure if it is possible and how to do it. I have been reading that through cloudwatch some metrics could be obtained.

Comment: Such statistics would need to come from _within_ the instance, since AWS does not have access to the instance itself. The operating system running on the instance is responsible for managing the storage on the disk volume itself.

Answer (score 1):

One way to monitor this is to setup a cron on your EC2 that would report the disk usage on a daily/monthly basis.

For instance if your cron ran a script like `$ df -hT /dev/xvda1` this would give you all the info you need about the mounted volume's i.e. status of disk usage.

You can publish the data of interest to metrics which is described here: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/monitoring/publishingMetrics.html#publishingDataPoints

And of course you can then setup alarms off those metrics to alert you when certain thresholds are being passed so you can act to increase disk size.